# How can I clear multiple caches using JCache annotation @CacheRemoveAll?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, jcache

I have a method who's execution should clear two caches in my Spring+JCache+ehcache 3.5 project.

I tried:

```
@CacheRemoveAll(cacheName = "cache1")
@CacheRemoveAll(cacheName = "cache2")
public void methodToBeCalled(){
}
```

and

```
@CacheRemoveAll(cacheName = "cache1", cacheName = "cache2")
public void methodToBeCalled(){
}
```

In the first I get:

```
Duplicate annotation of non-repeatable type @CacheRemoveAll
```

In the second I get:

```
Duplicate attribute cacheName in annotation @CacheRemoveAll
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Annotations can't be repeated and attributes can't be repeated.

You would need a `@CacheRemoveAlls` annotation but the framework hasn't planned that.

Your best solution is simply to call `removeAll` for your two caches at the beginning of `methodToBeCalled`.

The code would be like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager; // this is a Spring CacheManager

    public void methodToBeCalled(){
        cacheManager.getCache("cache1").clear();
        cacheManager.getCache("cache2").clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I call this method in Java code? I ask because I set up the cache using ehcache.xml and spring xml servlet configuration and I'm only using it via annotations. So how can I reference it in code?

Comment: Like everything in Spring. You inject it. I will update my answer to show you.